# Angular doesn't resolve module which is clearly in node_modules

Tags: angular, npm

I generated an Angular library to handle authentication so that I could re-use it in all of my angular projects through NPM.
I developed it using npm link and had it working well so I then published it privately to npm, deleted the symlinks and when I attempted to verify that it was still good in the same project that it had been working perfectly well in I get the following now:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@myscope/authentication/authentication.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'authentication' in 'D:\projects\git-hub\sandbox\verify-authentication\node_modules\@myscope\authentication'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'authentication' in 'D:\projects\git-hub\sandbox\verify-authentication\src\app'
```

I know that I correctly included it in my package.json because running npm install did result in a @myscope/authentication directory in node_modules with all of the essential files especially the authentication module which Angular can not find.

When the authentication directory within my node_modules/@myscope/ directory was a symlink to my angular projects dist/authentication directory then it worked well.

Intelij doesn't reveal any obvious errors and autocomplete finds the relevant resources because the IDE at least knows that they're there.

How can I get useful feedback to troubleshoot then correct this problem?

Comment: Try put file path in angular.json file under "architect-> build-> options -> scripts",
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/@myscope/filename.js"
             ]

Comment: I just tried:
              "./node_modules/@avaramis/authentication/esm2015/public-api.js",
              "./node_modules/@avaramis/authentication/esm2015/authentication.js"
And neither one helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get my library to work with `npm link` I had to add `"enableIvy":false` to my tsconfig.json's `angularCompilerOptions` property object.
As I learned from [issue #35586](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35586).

However in order to get my library to work AFTER I'm done with `npm link` then the inverse is apparently needed (with an equally clear way of knowing so).

It would really help a lot if `.json` allowed comments. When it exists as hard coded significant software configuration files comments would really help developers manage and develop that software.

So in conclusion the lessons learned:
To develop Angular 9 libraries with `npm link` tsconfig.json needs to look like this:

```js
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
  "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  // Remove after you finish with npm link and publish to npm
  "enableIvy": false
}
```

But you can't have that so instead you must have:

```json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
  "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  "enableIvy": false
}
```

And then when you publish it must change to:

```json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
  "strictInjectionParameters": true,
}
```

You could also toggle `false` to `true` since `true` is the default.